# How to make decimal alignment in lines that is not in table?

Tags: alignment

I am making a file in which there are many lines. In every line there is a number. Can I make those numbers decimal alignment?

I am using Latex.

Thanks.

My codes are:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cdotfill{%
    \leavevmode\cleaders\hb@xt@.44em{\hss$\cdot$\hss}\hfill\kern\z@
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Car\cdotfill 11111.55 dollar\par
House\cdotfill 2222.1 dollar
\end{document}
```

I want to make 11111.55 and 2222.1 decimal alignment.

Comment: Could you please post a sketch of what you're expecting? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: @Bernard  I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: why not make that a table using `tabular` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  It is a list not a tabular.

Comment: `tabular` is just a way to make things align, it doesn't have to be used for things that are logically a table (for example article class uses it to set author names)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But I need to use ellipsis between the numbers and the nouns and after the numbers there are nouns. So, even in tabular, how can I make it successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cdotfill{%
    \leavevmode\cleaders\hb@xt@.44em{\hss$\cdot$\hss}\hfill\kern\z@
}
\newlength\twodplength
\settowidth\twodplength{.12}
\def\twodp#1{\@twodp#1..\relax}
\def\@twodp#1.#2.#3{%
#1\makebox[\twodplength][l]{\if!#2!\else.#2\fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Car\cdotfill \twodp{11111.55} dollar\par
House\cdotfill \twodp{2222.1} dollar\par
TeX\cdotfill \twodp{0} dollar\par
\end{document}
```

This sets everything after the whole number part on a box the width of `.12`

Comment: You are so nice. But most of your codes can't be understood by me. May you tell me how can I be as excellent as you of Latex?

Comment: @Y.zeng I have been doing this since 1987, I have had a bit of practice.

Comment: How about recommending some books for me?

Comment: @Y.zeng https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Comment: That book is not much detailed.

Comment: @Y.zeng there are 43 answers in that post suggesting different resources for learning latex, I do not know which book you mean.

Comment: The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε